# How to get the number of days in a given month in Ruby, accounting for year?

Tags: ruby, date

I'm sure there's a good simple elegant one-liner in Ruby to give you the number of days in a given month, accounting for year, such as "February 1997".  What is it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is the implementation from ActiveSupport (a little adapted):

```
COMMON_YEAR_DAYS_IN_MONTH = [nil, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

def days_in_month(month, year = Time.now.year)
   return 29 if month == 2 && Date.gregorian_leap?(year)
   COMMON_YEAR_DAYS_IN_MONTH[month]
end
```

Comment: Btw, originally implemented in module Time.

Comment: super dated at this point. look at some of the other answers.

Comment: If you are using rails, @mkosma has a simpler answer.

Answer (score 140):

If you're working in Rails, chances are you'll get hamstrung eventually if you switch among `Time`, `Date`, and `DateTime`, especially when it comes to dealing with UTC/time zones, daylight savings, and the like. My experience has been it's best to use `Time`, and stick with it everywhere.

So, assuming you're using Rails's Time class, there are two good options, depending on context:

1. If you have a month `m` and year `y`, use the class method on `Time`:

   ```
   days = Time.days_in_month(m, y)
   ```
2. If you have a Time object `t`, cleaner to ask the day number of the last day of the month:

   ```
   days = t.end_of_month.day
   ```

Comment: Thanks! but not really -- OP asked about ruby, not rails. 

I'd be interested to know how many folks are working in Ruby Off Rails, though.

Comment: I use ruby outside rails and this answer would be no good for me.

Comment: @SteveRawlingson Get your career on track then! :P

Comment: I'm implementing a gem where this is needed, and I cannot assume the user would use the gem inside Rails. So I really think that, although cleaner, this should not be the accepted answer. It's very nice to have it here in context as well, cause lots of people would prefer this option when in Rails.

Comment: Working on Ruby project do not forbid you using activesupport gem.
Source : https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport

Comment: I don't use Rails, but generally I find the time stuff from ActiveSupport is worth cherry-picking into any project that deals with dates and times like this.

Answer (score 75):

```
require 'date'

def days_in_month(year, month)
  Date.new(year, month, -1).day
end

# print number of days in February 2012
puts days_in_month(2012, 2)
```

Comment: btw I didn't need to require Date in my ruby only program.

Comment: You only didn't need to require date because it has already been required elsewhere.

Answer (score 24):

How about:

```
require 'date'

def days_in_month(year, month)
  (Date.new(year, 12, 31) << (12-month)).day
end

# print number of days in Feburary 2009
puts days_in_month(2009, 2)
```

You may also want to look at [Time::days_in_month](http://dev.rubyonrails.org/browser/trunk/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb?rev=8715) in Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Could you explain what make this def? Because I like but I want to understand

Comment: @Mike Wade, this assumes we know December has 31 days. What about if we don't even know that?

Comment: December will always have 31 days.

Comment: @nemesisfixx, you can work off Jan 1 instead of Dec 31.  ((Date.new(year+1, 1, 1) - 1.day) << (12-month)).day

Comment: @IsaacBetesh, yep get it `((Date.new(2013+1, 1, 1) - day_offset) << (12-month)).day` works for me :-)

Comment: `<< (12-month)).day` doesn't seem very readable / understandable / maintainable, whereas `year, month, -1` seems much more obvious - to me.

Answer (score 13):

In Rails project for current date

```
Time.days_in_month(Time.now.month, Time.now.year)
```

For any date **t** which is instance of Time

```
Time.days_in_month(t.month, t.year)
```

or

```
t.end_of_month.day
```

.
If you have UTC **seconds**, you need to get an instance of Time first

```
Time.at(seconds).end_of_month.day
```

Answer (score 9):

For a given Date object I feel like the easiest is:

```
Date.today.all_month.count
```

Comment: Docs for `all_month` can be found [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-all_month).

Answer (score 7):

Use `Time.days_in_month(month)` where `month = 1` for January, `2` for Feb, etc.

Answer (score 4):

revise the input for other format

```
def days_in_a_month(date = "2012-02-01")
  date.to_date.end_of_month.day
end
```

Answer (score 3):

as of rails 3.2... there's a built in version:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-c-days_in_month

(alas, it shows up after this answer, which takes folks on a long hike)

Answer (score 3):

`Time.now.end_of_month.day` - for current month

`Date.parse("2014-07-01").end_of_month.day` - use date of first day in month.

Depends on ActiveSupport

Comment: You could also do `Date.today.end_of_month.day`

Answer (score 3):

A simple way using `Date`:

```
def days_of_month(month, year)
  Date.new(year, month, -1).day
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's the simplest way to get it

```
def get_number_of_days(date = Date.today)
  Date.new(date.year, date.month, -1).mday
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the time is irrelevant for this purpose then you just need a date object:

```
[*Date.today.all_month].size
```

Comment: Time is not irrelevant, the OP wants to know the number of days *in a given month, such as february 1997*

Comment: What I meant is that since we don't need either hours, minutes or seconds then a Time object is not necessary. Therefore, a Date object is more than enough in this case.

Comment: I prefer to use a Time object when I can, so as not to have to pull the Date object from the library.