# Get the end of current month in RubyMotion as a Time object

Tags: ios, rubymotion

I need to get the end of the current calendar month in rubymotion as a Time object.

So for the month of October 2012, given the current time I'd need October 31, 2012 Midnight as an instance of `Time`, regardless of the current day.

How do I do this?

**EDIT**

I appreciate the answers, but one thing I neglected to mention - sorry - is that I am using RubyMotion and the Date and DateTime objects are not available.

Basically, anything that you load with `require` in ruby, I do not have access to.

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489826/how-to-get-the-number-of-days-in-a-given-month-in-ruby-accounting-for-year

Comment: I don't need the number of days in the month, I need to get a Time object for the end of the calendar month given the current time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using RubyMotion you have access to all the iOS SDKs:

```
NSDate *curDate = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents* comps = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:curDate]; // Get necessary date components

    comps = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:curDate]; // Get necessary date components
    // set last of month
    [comps setMonth:[comps month]+1];
    [comps setDay:0];
    NSDate *tDateMonth = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
    NSLog(@"%@", tDateMonth);
```

Found at [Getting the last day of a month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772348/nsdate-getting-the-last-day-of-a-month)

Translation to RubyMotion:

```
    curDate = NSDate.date
    calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar

    # Get necessary date components
    comps = calendar.components(NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSWeekdayCalendarUnit, fromDate:curDate)

    # set last of month
    comps.month += 1
    comps.day = 0
    tDateMonth = calendar.dateFromComponents(comps)
    NSLog("%@", tDateMonth)
```

Comment: I'm new to iOS development, but not to ruby, so I forget about these things (*facepalm*) Thanks!

Comment: For the record, looking at the verbosity of that objective-c snippet reminds me of why I love ruby. :P

Comment: I translated it to `RubyMotion`.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick..

```
require 'date'
(DateTime.now.next_month - DateTime.now.day).to_time
```

Example:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p194 :001 > require 'date'
 => true 

ruby-1.9.3-p194 :02 > DateTime.now
 => #<DateTime: 2012-10-10T17:18:15-05:00 ((2456211j,80295s,284081000n),-18000s,2299161j)> 

ruby-1.9.3-p194 :03 > DateTime.now.next_month - DateTime.now.day
 => #<DateTime: 2012-10-31T17:18:16-05:00 ((2456232j,80296s,819683000n),-18000s,2299161j)> 

ruby-1.9.3-p194 :04 > (DateTime.now.next_month - DateTime.now.day).to_time
 => 2012-10-31 17:18:18 -0500
```

Comment: next_month is Rails, not Ruby.

Comment: @steenslag: nah, it's [Ruby 1.9.3](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-next_month).

Comment: May not be relevant to the OP, but watch out for DST changes

Comment: @maerics completely missed all of those methods.

Comment: @steenslag: yeah, i had to double-check myself =)

Answer (score 0):

**Ruby on Rails** method

```
Time.now.at_end_of_month
```

Answer (score 0):

You could increment the "start" datetime until it rolls to the next month:

```ruby
require 'date'

def last_day_of_month(date=DateTime.now)
  month = date.month
  date += 1 while month == (date + 1).month
  date.to_time
end

last_day_of_month # => 2012-10-31 16:17:21 -0600
nov_1_2010 = DateTime.parse('2010-11-01T01:01:01-0700')
last_day_of_month(nov_1_2010) # => 2010-11-30 01:01:01 -0700
```